# Difference between should, must, can, may

Tags: grammar, word-usage, differences

Difference  between should, must, can, may in a conversation and a sentence.

Comment: Usually, ***can** = ability, **may** = possibility,  **should** = recommendation, **must** = obligation.* But there are many exceptions and other differences, and listing all of them would be beyond the scope of a single Question + Answer here.

Comment: Hint:  When you're writing your question and have just entered the title, look at the list of "Questions that may already have your answer" before you go any further.

Answer (score 1):

Should: "Ideally, you'd do this/we'd prefer it if you did this/it's in your best interests to do this for whatever reason, but you don't have to if you really don't want to," though sometimes it carries the force of a politely-worded command/requirement rather than just a strong suggestion (the difference can be best ascertained by the speaker and listener's hierarchical relationship, if any).

Must: You have to do this, whether because it's the rules, whatever you're trying to accomplish simply won't work if you don't, or because I'm commanding you too and I'm in a position to give commands.

Can: You have the capability of doing this if you so choose.  Often carries the additional force of "it won't make much of a practical difference either way" or "it's purely a matter of taste/preference."

May: Very similar to "can," though often (but not always) additionally implies the granting of permission in a scenario where permission is needed.